# UISwipeGestureRecognizer Swipe Distance

Tags: iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

Any idea if there is a simple way to lengthen the distance a swipe has to travel before being recognized. Seems the the default is really short. It's more than a tap, but just barely. Do I need to create a custom gesture recognizer to override this distance?

Thanks.

Comment: From the docs: Swipes can be slow or fast. A slow swipe requires high directional precision but a small distance; a fast swipe requires low directional precision but a large distance. Just pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having no documented properties to set that means there're no documented properties to set that. You can create your own gesture recognizer, though.

---

There are 7 *undocumented* properties to change the default behavior:

```
@interface UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
@property(assign, nonatomic) CGFloat minimumPrimaryMovement;
@property(assign, nonatomic) CGFloat maximumPrimaryMovement;
@property(assign, nonatomic) CGFloat minimumSecondaryMovement;
@property(assign, nonatomic) CGFloat maximumSecondaryMovement;
@property(assign, nonatomic) NSTimeInterval maximumDuration;
@property(assign, nonatomic) float rateOfMinimumMovementDecay;
@property(assign, nonatomic) float rateOfMaximumMovementDecay;
@end
```

but if you write for AppStore you can't use these.

Comment: I won't be using private APIs, but  your answer is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to display those values to see default values. But I get weird values. Did you manage to do it ? My Code :  NSLog (@"minimumPrimaryMovement : %f, maximumPrimaryMovement %f, minimumSecondaryMovement %f, maximumSecondaryMovement %f, maximumDuration %f, [swipeRecognizer minimumPrimaryMovement], [swipeRecognizer maximumPrimaryMovement], [swipeRecognizer minimumSecondaryMovement], [swipeRecognizer maximumSecondaryMovement], [swipeRecognizer maximumDuration]);